# Get ADFS claims using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-on-prem, adfs

Anyone using ADFS with 2016. We would like to get users claims in a SPFX webpart or with JavaScript. Can't find anything on the topic

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find the solution, or is there any solution to get the ADFS token using JS

Comment: No there is not unfortunately